# I left Car. Reaper seedlings in the tray for 51 days, did I leave them in too long?

Tags: indoors, seedlings, transplanting, peppers

I left my carolina reapers in the starter tray for 51 days, the bottom of the stems are starting to get woody, and they have about 5 sets of true leaves and are still growing more. They are ~2.5 inches tall.

If I transplant them into pots now, will they grow bigger or did I wait too long? Can I still wait longer? I am growing them indoors only, so I have plenty of time to wait for them to get large.

Comment: Maybe add a photo of the situation?

Comment: I ended up just transplanting them. They were root bound. Sorry for the lack of information about the starter trays and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be fine to transplant them now into slightly bigger pots.  I am guessing they are in a starter tray with 1" diameter 'pots'? Upgrade only to 3 or 4 inch diameter pots...with potting soil.  Hard to imagine what you've got going but if your plants are still alive there is no reason to quit.  50 days is a stretch but plants are tough.  Just squeeze the bottom of the little pot as you turn upside down...if roots are through the bottom, just rip or cut them off to release the start from its starting pot.  Transplant into  3 or 4" diameter pot, firm the soil and water, only water when pot feels light as you lift it.  Are you using artificial light or sunlight?  You really need a decent grow light to grow them indoors.  The light from the window is not enough and the winter daylight hours are too short. Not to mention you'll be responsible for pollination (no big deal). Careful with the nitrogen or you will not get flowers and peppers.  When roots grow through the bottom of the 3 to 4" pots repot into 6" pots.  Usually that is as far as you need to go for lots of peppers.  You have to have enough light via artificial means and a fan to blow the air.  All potting soil, no garden soil or compost.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have been growing indoor plants for a while now, I grew a loofah plant in my closet. Everything is exactly as you described, yes. I replanted them into sanitized soft drink cups that I cut in half. I have several grow lights, 4 covering my entire growing area by the window, and one that is now aimed directly on my plants. I am also using sunlight when it comes through. Can you elaborate about the nitrogen? I'm using 6-4-4 FoxFarm Grow Big. Oh, and I'm using pro-mix biofungicide mycorrhizae which works very well for me. And I have a huge honeywell circulating air.

Comment: Okay, did some research myself. I'm gonna find some 5-10-10, I have only been fertilizing them every once in a while since they are still seedlings. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Fox Farm is an excellent brand.  I am stumped with the term biofungicide (a biological means of killing fungus in this case a bacteria that kills fungus in the soil) and then combined with Mycorrhizae fungus.  Huh?  I am sure I am missing something.  I don't like the idea of applying a fungicide in potting soil anyway.  That soil should already be sterilized as it is a potting soil.  Peat is sort of antifungal/antibacterial itself.  But we do have to start boycotting the use of peat as it is an endangered resource as well as ecosystem.  Do your cups have drain holes? Scimp on the fertilizer

Comment: I just had a thought, you said you were supplementing the grow lights with daylight through the windows?  What is your daylight/dark cycle?

Comment: About 7 to 7, might switch to longer hours. I have mint, basil, milkweed, asperagus, dragonfruit and three types of peppers in the same spot, and everything is fine. My reapers are turning lime green though, hoping the fertilizer and more space helps. I just bought three pack of fox farm, I'm gonna follow that feeding schedule. Ya the cups have drainage holes.

Comment: increase to 12/12.  Normally plants are started with blue spectrum lights and the hours 18/6 18hours light then 6 hours darkness. Then to push plants into reproductive growth/ 12/12.  The switch is accompanied by changing your bulbs out from blue to the red spectrum.  Allowing a bit of light to enter the darkness during the dark phase can set you back big time.  Very sensitive.  Asparagus takes a minimum of  3 years to mature enough for harvest.  If you get asparagus spikes do not eat them because they are part of the maturation process...just set you back another year?  Do you have an outdoor

Comment: Not worried about the asperagus, really. Peppers are doing well, and my loofah did fine with very bad light schedule, as did the corn in my closet. Borage is very sensitive however and I have basically given up with that after my last full one. Thank you again for the advice, but this is getting close to needing to be a chat.

Comment: @d4rks1gm  'Corn in your closet'...growing Loofah and Borage is sensitive?  Wow.  What an experiment you've got going!  Borage is kind of a big weed.  I am dying to know what caused Borage to be so sensitive!  I am not saying I do not believe you I am saying your choices of plants and obviously you know a thing or TWO are really cool to observe.  Borage...CORN in your closet?  This is too much fun.  Did you really get corn to eat?  Kudos just for trying.  Good name for a book in the future; Corn In My Closet...!!

Comment: This soil that has biofungicides that is also mixed with Mycorrhizae fungus is still a conundrum.  Do you see what I am saying?  How big is your closet????  Grins.  Anytime, we can talk in chat.  I've not gotten the big sign saying 'this conversation needs to be...' yet, have you?

Comment: 40-60 sq feet. The corn got to 3-4 feet tall then I didn't repot it so it got sad, otherwise it would have done great, but that was with miracle grow. http://www.pthorticulture.com/en/products/pro-mix-bx-biofungicide-plus-mycorrhizae/ works great. Don't see any problems. Borage has been difficult, and it's not mold/fungus. Pretty sure it's a watering issue. Peppers are doing good, they are already growing new dark green leaves.

Comment: The loofah did fruit as well, I am in the process of drying them out, now.

Comment: Too amazing @d4rks1gm and way cool that you are doing this...please stay in touch!  I don't even know what a loofah plant LOOKS like, grins!  What incredible gifts for Xmas!  Home grown loofah, with some great home made soaps, raffia and a wooden boat to hold both...whatever.  Too cool...

Comment: I don't k ow how to stay in touch but if you do, cool. My email is my username at gmail with a dot after first 4 characters.